# Vim and ASCII extended characters?

Tags: vim

I would like to know how can I set VIM 7.0 to show and work with ASCII extended characters without problem.

Comment: Define "ASCII extended characters". Also, which `vi`? `vim`?

Comment: My vi *does* show and work with ASCII extended characters without problem, and I did not change anything. You need to be more specific about your configuration. What locale are you using? Which encoding is used by your terminal? What happens when you try to enter an extender character in vi?

Comment: I can only visualize 7-bit Ascii characters. Using VIM 7.0. Terminal is using latin1 encoding by default, and showing ? for the extended characters. When setting it to utf-8, those characters become <e9>, <e1>, <f3>, etc.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim (which is what `vi` resolves to on most systems) readily supports extended character sets. You might need to tell Vim *which* encoding to use, though.

This is controlled by two options:

```
:set encoding
:set fileencoding
```

If you have loaded a file that displays incorrectly, you may use `:set encoding=<new encoding>` to force the appropriate encoding. This changes the interpretation of the characters on the fly. If you want to save the file in another encoding *preserving the current interpretation of characters*, use `set fileencoding=<new encoding>` to let Vim save the file in that encoding.

I recommend that you set `utf-8` as the default encoding in your `.vimrc`.

Comment: Thanks Konrad, I did as you commented so getting a bit more into VIM. Yet, when setting the encoding to utf-8 the characters become <e9>, <e1>, <f3>, etc. I've read about setting guifont but when trying to set it I got a not supported message. I'm using VIM 7.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Once the the characters are "extended" it's not ASCII any more.

However: Just use vim. ":help unicode" for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions here didn't work for me. Vim told me that `encoding` and `fileencoding` were not supported options. That turned out to be because I was building from source myself, and I did not include the multi-byte feature. My two Macs are similar, but one of them enabled it by default while the other did not.

If you're building Vim from source like I was, include `--enable-multibyte` in your arguments to `./configure`. In my case, Vim defaulted to UTF-8 and supported extended characters after that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try the following:

- set the terminal to utf-8 (how to do that depends on your terminal; in PuTTY it's in the Window/Translation menu)
- set your locale to utf-8 (how to do that depends on your OS; on my Debian box it's `set LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8` for the current session and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` for permanent system-wide changes) -- you can check your current locale with `locale`.

That's how it works for me (using VIM 7.1.314 and no `.vimrc`).