# Apache redirect Logical Negation ¬ to Tilde ~

Tags: apache, redirect, special-characters, tilde, negation

I have a URL that I want to redirect however, I can't seem to enter the character into vim.

The character is ¬ (Logical Negation) and I want to redirect it to ~ (Tilde).

```
Redirect permanent /¬foo http://www.example.com/~foo
```

Vim won't let me copy this character into the terminal and I don't have it in my keyboard!

Comment: I've answered anyway, but for future reference questions like this are probably a better fit on serverfault rather than stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the info - will post there next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is more information about your wild character:**

http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/logical-negation-symbol-ascii-code-170.html

Install yudit, It is a unicode editor, you might be able to insert it easier with that.

In mathamatics speak, The statement ¬A is true if and only if A is false.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation

You may have to set your encoding preferences in vi as explained here:

[Vim and ASCII extended characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921316/vim-and-ascii-extended-characters)

**How to add Logical Negation character to VI:**

In VI, go into insert mode.  While in INSERT mode press:

Ctrl-v 172

Where 172 is the character code representing the character you want.  This assumes you are using the default encoding ISO 8859-1.

**You may be wondering why the logical not is `170` in extended ASCII but in VI you gotta type `172` to get that character?  Because you are using ISO 8859-1:**

http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/charset/iso160-191.html

**I am highly skeptical that Apache is going to do what you want**

You're probably going to be a lot more clever than you already are to pull it off.  Your Logical Not character is going to be re-encoded between the client's browser and the Apache server.

http://www.packetizer.com/labs/cs/characters.cgi?text=%C2%AC&submit=Submit

Comment: Thanks - it seems it was an issue with vim. The ctrl-V 172 allowed me to input the correct character.

Answer (score 3):

That's a non-ASCII character, so the URI that a browser would send to your server if a user requested `/¬foo` should be `/%C2%ACfoo` (with the ¬ character encoded as UTF-8 and each byte of the UTF-8 then URI encoded) or possibly just `/%ACfoo` (if the browser doesn't do the UTF-8 conversion first).  Try configuring a redirect for the encoded form(s) instead of the raw form.